# How to use this php function?

Tags: php, function

Let's say i have  this function but i don't know how to call it...

```
echo getYoutubeSearchVideosFeeds($variables);
```

with what i should replace $variables to call $q, $orderby, $startIndex and so on?

```
function getYoutubeSearchVideosFeeds($criteria) {
    $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?';
    $q = urlencode($criteria['q']);
    $orderby = $criteria['orderby']; // relevance, published, viewCount, rating
    $startIndex = $criteria['start-index'];
    $maxResults = $criteria['max-results'];
    $author = $criteria['author'];
    $format = $criteria['format'];
    $lr = $criteria['lr']; // fr, en
    $safeSearch = $criteria['safeSearch']; //none, moderate, strict

  // more code 
}
```

Comment: Where did this function come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it an associative array with the values listed in the function:

```
getYoutubeSearchVideosFeeds(array('q' => '...', 'orderby' => '...', ...));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array populated with values for each of the keys the function requires:

```
 getYoutubeSearchVideosFeeds(array('q' => '...',  'orderby' => '...'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getYoutubeSearchVideosFeeds(

array(

"q"=>"CriteriaValuesHere..GetItFromGDataHelp",
"start-index" => "Other Values"
.
.
.        
)


);
```